# How to separate comma separated and where condition in LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq, c#-4.0

I have a **giftcardamounts** in database table.

Column contains dollar and comma separated values.
There are 40 rows.

Ex:

```
row 1: giftcardamounts : ($10,$20,$30,$40,$50)
row 2: giftcardamounts : ($100,$200,$30,$40,$50)
row 3: giftcardamounts : ($10,$20,$300,$400,$500)
...etc
```

From frontend there is an input is **giftcardselectedamount**

Ex: **giftcardselectedamount=500**

Based on this input amount in need to write LINQ query on dollar and comma separated list of Values.

Please help me how to write this.

Comment: I need to write a linq where condition query on dallar and comma separated values in a column.

Comment: Understood, so what have you tried? We are here to help you, but not to write it for you. You need to have made an attempt and got stuck somewhere.

Comment: Yah I tried for a single string comma seperated. First I seperated with dollar and then comma. Example :(10,20,30,40,50,) but how to do with list'

Comment: store items in List<string> then use .contains() method to search for item if this what you want!

Comment: @khaledsaleh That will not work very well. What if there was a $5000 amount in one of the rows? It would match on 500 and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like commenters have noted, you should show some effort in reaching to an answer. Also your question isn't quite clear. Are you asking to return the row with a matching amount? If so you can try the following approach, which returns the first row that contains the dollar amount specified:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new[] {
        "$10,$20,$30,$40,$50",
        "$100,$200,$30,$40,$50",
        "$10,$20,$300,$400,$500"};

    var giftcardSelectedAmount = 500M;

    var matchingRow = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x
        .Split(',')
        .Any(v => decimal.Parse(v, NumberStyles.Currency) == giftcardSelectedAmount));
        
    Console.WriteLine(matchingRow);
}
```

I can easily modify this answer to return all matching rows, a count of occurrences, or a count of rows with occurrences. Let me know if you need any of these modifications and I can modify my answer to add these.